# Programatically rename file numbers with VBScript

Tags: shell, vbscript

I think I want to user VBScript but I could use a batch file.

I want to rename some files I have which are named like this:

```
Season (1)
Season (2)
..snip..
Season (9)
Season (10)
Season (11)
Season (12)
```

to:

```
Season (01)
Season (02)
..snip..
Season (09)
Season (10)
Season (11)
Season (12)
```

Rather than doing this manually for the 100+ TV shows I have that have more than 10 seasons, is there a way to achieve this programagically? Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to build a VBScript to do such a thing, many builtin softwares will do that for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=software+windows+rename+files&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I know of these, half of them don't/can't do what you want because of some ridiculous licensing restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript you can do something like this:

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder("C:\test")

For i = 1 To 15
    strPath = objFolder.Path & "\Season (" & i & ")"
    If Not objFso.FolderExists(strPath) Then objFso.CreateFolder strPath
Next

For Each objSubfolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    strName = objSubfolder.Name
    intPos1 = InStr(strName, "(")
    intPos2 = InStr(strName, ")")
    strOrder = Mid(strName, intPos1 + 1, intPos2 - intPos1 - 1)
    If Len(strOrder) = 1 Then
        objSubfolder.Name = Left(strName, intPos1) _
                            & "0" & strOrder _
                            & Right(strName, Len(strName) - intPos2 + 1)
    End If
Next
```

This will look at every subfolder in a given folder and find the season number.  If it's a single digit, it pads that number and renames the folder.  Code is tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

In VB/VBA it'd be something along the lines of:

```
For x = 1 to 100 ' or however many you have
Name "Season (" & cstr(x) & ")" as "Season (" & Format(x,"00") & ")"
Next
```

Or this (again in VB/VBA) can generate the commands you'd need in a bat file:

```
Sub Thing()

Dim x As Long

For x = 1 To 100 ' or however many you have
  Debug.Print "Ren " & Chr$(34) & "Season (" & CStr(x) & ")" & Chr$(34) & " " _
  & Chr$(34) & "Season (" & Format(x, "00") & ")" & Chr$(34)
Next

End Sub
```

to give you this:

```
Ren "Season (1)" "Season (01)"
Ren "Season (2)" "Season (02)"
Ren "Season (3)" "Season (03)"
Ren "Season (4)" "Season (04)"
Ren "Season (5)" "Season (05)"
Ren "Season (6)" "Season (06)"
Ren "Season (7)" "Season (07)"
Ren "Season (8)" "Season (08)"
Ren "Season (9)" "Season (09)"
Ren "Season (10)" "Season (10)"
Ren "Season (11)" "Season (11)"
Ren "Season (12)" "Season (12)"
Ren "Season (13)" "Season (13)"
Ren "Season (14)" "Season (14)"
Ren "Season (15)" "Season (15)"
Ren "Season (16)" "Season (16)"
Ren "Season (17)" "Season (17)"
Ren "Season (18)" "Season (18)"
Ren "Season (19)" "Season (19)"
Ren "Season (20)" "Season (20)"
Ren "Season (21)" "Season (21)"
Ren "Season (22)" "Season (22)"
Ren "Season (23)" "Season (23)"
Ren "Season (24)" "Season (24)"
Ren "Season (25)" "Season (25)"
Ren "Season (26)" "Season (26)"
Ren "Season (27)" "Season (27)"
Ren "Season (28)" "Season (28)"
Ren "Season (29)" "Season (29)"
Ren "Season (30)" "Season (30)"
Ren "Season (31)" "Season (31)"
Ren "Season (32)" "Season (32)"
Ren "Season (33)" "Season (33)"
Ren "Season (34)" "Season (34)"
Ren "Season (35)" "Season (35)"
Ren "Season (36)" "Season (36)"
Ren "Season (37)" "Season (37)"
Ren "Season (38)" "Season (38)"
Ren "Season (39)" "Season (39)"
Ren "Season (40)" "Season (40)"
Ren "Season (41)" "Season (41)"
Ren "Season (42)" "Season (42)"
Ren "Season (43)" "Season (43)"
Ren "Season (44)" "Season (44)"
Ren "Season (45)" "Season (45)"
Ren "Season (46)" "Season (46)"
Ren "Season (47)" "Season (47)"
Ren "Season (48)" "Season (48)"
Ren "Season (49)" "Season (49)"
Ren "Season (50)" "Season (50)"
Ren "Season (51)" "Season (51)"
Ren "Season (52)" "Season (52)"
Ren "Season (53)" "Season (53)"
Ren "Season (54)" "Season (54)"
Ren "Season (55)" "Season (55)"
Ren "Season (56)" "Season (56)"
Ren "Season (57)" "Season (57)"
Ren "Season (58)" "Season (58)"
Ren "Season (59)" "Season (59)"
Ren "Season (60)" "Season (60)"
Ren "Season (61)" "Season (61)"
Ren "Season (62)" "Season (62)"
Ren "Season (63)" "Season (63)"
Ren "Season (64)" "Season (64)"
Ren "Season (65)" "Season (65)"
Ren "Season (66)" "Season (66)"
Ren "Season (67)" "Season (67)"
Ren "Season (68)" "Season (68)"
Ren "Season (69)" "Season (69)"
Ren "Season (70)" "Season (70)"
Ren "Season (71)" "Season (71)"
Ren "Season (72)" "Season (72)"
Ren "Season (73)" "Season (73)"
Ren "Season (74)" "Season (74)"
Ren "Season (75)" "Season (75)"
Ren "Season (76)" "Season (76)"
Ren "Season (77)" "Season (77)"
Ren "Season (78)" "Season (78)"
Ren "Season (79)" "Season (79)"
Ren "Season (80)" "Season (80)"
Ren "Season (81)" "Season (81)"
Ren "Season (82)" "Season (82)"
Ren "Season (83)" "Season (83)"
Ren "Season (84)" "Season (84)"
Ren "Season (85)" "Season (85)"
Ren "Season (86)" "Season (86)"
Ren "Season (87)" "Season (87)"
Ren "Season (88)" "Season (88)"
Ren "Season (89)" "Season (89)"
Ren "Season (90)" "Season (90)"
Ren "Season (91)" "Season (91)"
Ren "Season (92)" "Season (92)"
Ren "Season (93)" "Season (93)"
Ren "Season (94)" "Season (94)"
Ren "Season (95)" "Season (95)"
Ren "Season (96)" "Season (96)"
Ren "Season (97)" "Season (97)"
Ren "Season (98)" "Season (98)"
Ren "Season (99)" "Season (99)"
Ren "Season (100)" "Season (100)"
```

Comment: With the first I get VBScript expected end of statement on line 2. The second is VBA, that's to be run in something like Excel, right? I'm working purely from Windows.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's VBA/VB6.  You'd have to translate to VBScript to use it there.  The last bit, with all the REN statements is the *result* of the second bit of code.  Copy and paste into a BAT file and run it after suitable editing.

Comment: I was hoping for a one line for loop in VBScript or some implementation of the FOR iterator on the Windows command line... thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't have time to learn VBScript in order to solve your problem for you.

Comment: I wasn't expecting anyone to learn anything for me, rather answer the question if they could.